# regex for alphanumeric and allow an additional character also

Tags: javascript, regex

How could I allow a string to match alphanumeric characters and a comma character
And have the input be a minimum of 6 and 50 max;

Now, it matches nothing, with or without the comma in it?

```
test = "dam, Amsterdam";
if( test.match(/^\w{6,50}\,$/) ){
```

thanks, Richard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^[\w, ]{6,50}$/
```

I've created a character class (the square brackets) and added comma and space.  The regex space is a way to allow the space after the comma in the input.  Note that it's never necessary to escape a comma in a regex.

Comment: Thank you, that worked, very nice. I will remember the square brackets.